# How to call function without using onClick

Tags: android

I am beginner of learning android. Here i want call `endfun(View v)` method  from `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method with out using `onClick`.Any one here to suggest me.

```
  package com.example.loginandroid;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Looper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    String username,password;     ResultSet rs =null;
    boolean temcfag=false,temqfag=true;
    public static String tag="Lifecycle activity";
    EditText user,pass;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setNeutralButton("OK", null);


        user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        //i want call here endfun(View v) with out using onclick 
    }



    public void endfun(View v) throws SQLException{
        if(rs!=null){

             if (rs.next()) {
               Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr1");
                       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
                    Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr1");
                     }
             else{

                  Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr2");
               dialog.setMessage("Your username and password are not valid");
                dialog.show();
                /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UserName :"+username+"\n"+"password :"+password+"\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr2");*/
             }}
            else{
                Log.v("out of loop","errorrrrrrrrrrr3");
            }
    }


}
```

Comment: `v` is not used in you method, why you pass that at all?

Comment: Your design is wrong.  You do not say **why** you want to do this, but you should never need to call click handlers.  Even if there is a real need, put the code into a method and call the method from your onClick handler and from where you need to in the rest of your code.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Because that's the required signature for an onClick handler.

Comment: @Simon so OP define onClick on xml file? i did not get first time, thanks.  if you want do this you can click your button by code with **performClick()**

Comment: @user3336440 do you actually have a button in your layout xml that uses this method via `onClick` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `null` as the parameter:

```
endfun(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

First method that will execute is `onCreate` after that call whatever you want.
Why are you passing a view when you don't need it.

Comment: because he is using an `onClick` attribute, as he mentioned in question.. so he most likely there is also a button in his layout with `onClick` attribute that calls this method